# In node pg client.query doesn't return

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku

I am currently updating a very old application to run on Heroku. I've had to update to the latest version of pg to support the latest postgres on heroku. However, this was originally abstracted out so it's all handled in the one file (below). I can connect to the DB successfully but `client.query` never returns.

The first `console.log` is `SELECT * FROM public.user WHERE "email" = $1 [ 'xx@xx.com' ]`. However, I never reach the second `console.log`. I get no connection errors.

I am using pg `7.x` and postgres 10.

Any ideas?

```js
const { Client } = require('pg');
const config = require('.././app/models/config.js');
const client = new Client({
 connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL || config.database || ''
});

var conString = config.database || '';

client.connect();

module.exports = {
 query: function(text, values, cb) {
  console.log(text, values);
  client.query(text, values, function(err, result) {

   console.log(err, result);

   if (err) {
    console.log(err);
   }
   if (cb) {
    cb(err, result);
   }
   client.end();
  });
 }
};
```

Comment: Did you ever work out what the problem was?  I'm using promises instead of callbacks but seeing the same issue - the promise is never resolved, so `await client.query()` behaves as if the function never returns.

Comment: Hey @Malvineous, same here, while it depends from what server I run the same code. Have you ever found a solution?

Comment: @StéphanedeLuca I haven't encountered the problem for a while but I think many `pg` versions have incompatibilities like this with recent NodeJS versions.  Now, any time I have a weird issue like this I update the `pg` module and it goes away (or I ensure I'm running one behind the latest NodeJS release, if the `pg` module hasn't been updated yet for the new NodeJS version).

Comment: I have the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT: I've edit with the correct promise from pg.** Due the asynchronous nature of Nodejs you have to work with promises, something like:

```
module.exports = {
  query: function(text, values) {
    console.log(text, values);
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        client.query(text, values)
         .then(function (res) { resolve(res.rows[0]) })
         .catch(function (e) { reject(e.stack) };
        });
  }
};
```

Then require you module and consume the promise:

```
var myPrevModule = require('module');

myPrevModule.query.then(function(resp){ 
 // Consume the callback here ...
}).catch(function(err){ 
   console.error(err); 
})
```

Comment: Thanks for replying but iI am using a callback parameter `cb` instead of using promises. This is very old code and I don't want to update all my models to use promises. The `node-pg` library does support callback params https://node-postgres.com/features/queries